# PHP echo with space and without space

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am using PHP Version 5.4.17 in my mac. Below code with space gives me error. Once I remove the space in echo command, it gives me output but appended with Junk character. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated

**Code**:

```
<?php
echo “Connection Success”;
?>
```

**Error**: 
"Parse error: parse error, expecting ','' or';'' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test org.php on line 2"

**Code**:

```
<?php
echo “ConnectionSuccess”;
?>
```

**Output**: 
â€œConnectionSuccessâ€

Comment: What editor are you using to write the code? It looks like your quotation marks aren't the standard " or ', but rather a styled version. You'll need a simple text editor, not one of the main ones built into OSX. For a free one, check out Smultron for instance. For a paid one, Sublime or TextMate are often the best choices.

Comment: Don't forget to an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo "ConnectionSuccess";
?>
```

Comment: aka "turn off smart quotes" in your editor

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the bad quotes `“` and `”` and replace them with standard quotes: `"`

Some editors do this for you automatically, like BareBones.

Comment: redolent is correct, “ is a different character from " and therefore the source of the error.

Comment: Issue is resolved by turning off smart quotes ....thanks for all help